# Setting Glue Script variable from Stepfunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions

I have several glue jobs running in a stepfunction that all depend on a date variable. If the stepfunction fails I will need to re-run the stepfunction for the date it failed. Is there a way to change the variable from the stepfunction json input? I have tried using parameters and input paths but I haven't been able to get it to change the glue script variable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by adding a job parameter key value pair in the glue jobs under the security options.

These are the keys I added

key | value

year:year 
month:month 
day:day

I then called the key from the stepfunction and set the value.

This is what I had as my core statemachine code.

````
{
  "Comment": "aws glue step function",
  "StartAt": "date_test",
  "States": {
    "date_test": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "Arg_Test",
        "Arguments": {
          "year.$": "$.year",
          "month.$": "$.month",
          "day.$": "$.day"
        }```
````

This is what I used as my input

```
{
    "year": "01",
  "month": "02",
  "day": "03"
}
```

When I Checked my glue variables they had changed to year:01 month:02 day:03